# Rank correlation with weights for frequencies, in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy, statistics, correlation

My data is a set of *n* observed pairs along with their frequencies, i.e. to each pair *(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)* there corresponds some *k<sub>i</sub>*, the number of times *(x<sub>i</sub>, y<sub>i</sub>)* was observed. Ideally, I would like to compute both Kendall's tau and Spearman's rho for the set of all the copies of these pairs, which consists of *k<sub>1</sub> + k<sub>2</sub> + ... + k<sub>n</sub>* pairs. The problem is that *k<sub>1</sub> + k<sub>2</sub> + ... + k<sub>n</sub>*, the total number of observations, is huge and such a data structure won't fit in the memory.

Naturally, I thought about assigning the frequency of *i*-th pair, *k<sub>i</sub>/(k<sub>1</sub> + k<sub>2</sub> + ... + k<sub>n</sub>)*, as its weight, and computing rank correlation for the weighted set — but I couldn't find any tools for that. In the weighted varieties of rank correlation I met (e.g., [scipy.stats.weightedtau](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weightedtau.html)), the weights represent the importance of ranks and not pairs, which is not relevant for my cause. Pearson's r seems to have exactly the weighting option I need, but it doesn't fit my purpose as *x* and *y* are nowhere linearly related. I was wondering if I'm missing out on some notion for generalized correlation on weighted data points.

The only idea I've got so far is to scale down *k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub>, ..., k<sub>n</sub>* by some common factor *c*, so that scaled number of copies of *i*-th pair is *[k<sub>i</sub>/c]* (here *[.]* is the rounding operator, as we need to have integer number of copies of each pair). By choosing *c* such that *[k<sub>1</sub>/c] + [k<sub>2</sub>/c] + ... + [k<sub>n</sub>/c]* pairs can fit into memory, we could then compute the correlation coefficients tau and rho for the resulting set. However, *k<sub>i</sub>* and *k<sub>j</sub>* can differ by many orders of magnitude, so *c* can be significantly big for some *k<sub>i</sub>* and thus rounding *k<sub>i</sub>/c* can cause information loss.

UPD: One can compute Spearman's rho along with p-value on a dataset with specified frequency weights as below:

```
def frequency_pearsonr(data, frequencies):
    """
    Calculates Pearson's r between columns (variables), given the
    frequencies of the rows (observations).

    :param data: 2-D array with data
    :param frequencies: 1-D array with frequencies
    :return: 2-D array with pairwise correlations,
        2-D array with pairwise p-values
    """
    df = frequencies.sum() - 2
    Sigma = np.cov(data.T, fweights=frequencies)
    sigma_diag = Sigma.diagonal()
    Sigma_diag_pairwise_products = np.multiply.outer(sigma_diag, sigma_diag)
    # Calculate matrix with pairwise correlations.
    R = Sigma / np.sqrt(Sigma_diag_pairwise_products)
    # Calculate matrix with pairwise t-statistics. Main diagonal should
    # get 1 / 0 = inf.
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        T = R / np.sqrt((1 - R * R) / df)
    # Calculate matrix with pairwise p-values.
    P = 2 * stats.t.sf(np.abs(T), df)

    return R, P


def frequency_rank(data, frequencies):
    """
    Ranks 1-D data array, given the frequency of each value. Same
    values get same "averaged" ranks. Array with ranks is shaped to
    match the input data array.

    :param data: 1-D array with data
    :param frequencies: 1-D array with frequencies
    :return: 1-D array with ranks
    """
    s = 0
    ranks = np.empty_like(data)
    # Compute rank for each unique value.
    for value in sorted(set(data)):
        index_grid = np.ix_(data == value)
        # Find total frequency of the value.
        frequency = frequencies[index_grid].sum()
        ranks[index_grid] = s + 0.5 * (frequency + 1)
        s += frequency    

    return ranks


def frequency_spearmanrho(data, frequencies):
    """
    Calculates Spearman's rho between columns (variables), given the
    frequencies of the rows (observations).

    :param data: 2-D array with data
    :param frequencies: 1-D array with frequencies
    :return: 2-D array with pairwise correlations,
        2-D array with pairwise p-values
    """
    # Rank the columns.
    ranks = np.empty_like(data)
    for i, data_column in enumerate(data.T):
        ranks[:, i] = frequency_rank(data_column, frequencies)
    # Compute Pearson's r correlation and p-values on the ranks.
    return frequency_pearsonr(ranks, frequencies)


# Columns are variables and rows are observations, whose frequencies
# are specified.
data_col1 = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
data_col2 = np.array([.67, .25, .75, .2, .6])
data_col3 = np.array([.1, .3, .8, .3, .2])
data = np.array([data_col1, data_col2, data_col3]).T
frequencies = np.array([2, 4, 1, 3, 2])

# Same data, but with observations (rows) actually repeated instead of
# their frequencies being specified.
expanded_data_col1 = np.array([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
expanded_data_col2 = np.array([.67, .67, .25, .25, .25, .25, .75, .2, .2, .2, .6, .6])
expanded_data_col3 = np.array([.1, .1, .3, .3, .3, .3, .8, .3, .3, .3, .2, .2])
expanded_data = np.array([expanded_data_col1, expanded_data_col2, expanded_data_col3]).T

# Compute Spearman's rho for data in both formats, and compare.
frequency_Rho, frequency_P = frequency_spearmanrho(data, frequencies)
Rho, P = stats.spearmanr(expanded_data)
print(frequency_Rho - Rho)
print(frequency_P - P)
```

The particular example above shows that both methods produce same correlations and same p-values:

```
[[  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  1.11022302e-16   0.00000000e+00  -5.55111512e-17]
 [  0.00000000e+00  -5.55111512e-17   0.00000000e+00]]
[[  0.00000000e+00  -1.35525272e-19   4.16333634e-17]
 [ -9.21571847e-19   0.00000000e+00  -5.55111512e-17]
 [  4.16333634e-17  -5.55111512e-17   0.00000000e+00]]
```

Comment: To compute the weighted Spearman rank correlation coefficient, you could simply pre-rank your x and y values and then push those into `pearsonr` (together with your weights) to get a weighted Spearman's rho back out.

Comment: Not sure about the statistical validity of the following approach, but from a technical standpoint, you could simply encapsulate a (pre-computed) dictionary mapping ranks to normalised frequencies in a function and pass that as a `weigher` to `weightedtau`.

Comment: Let me get your question straight, <i>k<sub>1</sub> + k<sub>2</sub> + ... + k<sub>n</sub></i> pair of observations are too large to fit in RAM.  Can you calculate rank correlation on a random sample, increase the sample size, repeat this process until the estimated rank correlation is below some threshold level?

Comment: @Paul, could you please clarify on what do you mean by "pre-rank"? 

I think your second suggestion makes sense, if ranks are anything distinct (e.g. indices) and exchange weight is the product of weights and not the sum ("additive=False"). Indeed, if (x1, y1) has occurred 5 times and (x2, y2) has occurred 10 times, then their exchange weight ∝ 50, which is exactly the number of times this exchange, (x1, y1) <-> (x2, y2), would have occurred if computing regular tau correlation on the "expanded" dataset with 5 instances of (x1, y1) and 10 instances of (x2, y2).

I'll test this and report.

Comment: @CTZhu Yes you got it right, k1 + k2 + ... + kn observations can't fit in the memory. In fact, it can be many orders of magnitude more than the memory capacities. I'm not sure what threshold you are talking about, since I don't have any priors on what the correlation should be. If for every sample size the correlation is significantly distinct (which is likely since any memory-feasible sample size is not nearly representative enough), what do we do then?

Comment: By "pre-rank" I meant that you could compute the ranks of your data before you push the data into `weightedtau` together with a dictionary encapsulated in a function mapping the pre-computed ranks to weights.

Comment: You would have to have some pretty special data for the statement "any memory-feasible sample size is not nearly representative enough" to be true. Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Paul I am not sure if I understand the notion of ranks in full. Do you think any arbitrary assignment of distinct ranks (say, by indices, i.e. rank of (x5, y5) is 5 and then weight of rank 5 is normalized k5) will work? Or do the ranks need to be computed in accordance to some rule? For the data, it's not about the specifity of it, it's about its size. Monte-Carlo approach only works properly if sample portion is above certain threshold. E.g. sample of size 10 is not representative for a population of size 10^20 as much different outcomes are possible and with significant probability each.

Comment: The rank of a value is the corresponding index in the sorted array. Also, I am almost certain that your opinion on the relationship between a population and a representative subsample is false. The necessary subsample size does not depend on the population size but on the smoothness of the underlying data space. If what you say were true, you could literally do no scientific research whatsoever, because pretty much all "populations" of scientific interest are so large that you could never determine the properties of all members of a "significant" fraction.

Comment: You might be right about the sampling, I'll educate myself better on the matter. Meanwhile, your suggested approach works as I've put it to an answer. Almost, since the p-value is missing. Meanwhile, I'll address computing weighted Spearman's rho via Pearson's r and see how does it map to actual Spearman's rho on the expanded data, in both correlation coefficient and the p-value.

Comment: @Paul It seems that your first answer, suggesting to use weighted Pearson's r as Spearman's rho, is wrong. Consider set of pairs P, [(0, 0.2), (0, 0.25), (1, 0.6), (1, 0.667), (1, 0.75)], and their weights [3, 4, 2, 2, 1], which corresponds to "expanded" set of pairs P_x, [(0, 0.2), (0, 0.2), (0, 0.2), (0, 0.25), (0, 0.25), (0, 0.25), (0, 0.25), (1, 0.6), (1, 0.6), (1, 0.667), (1, 0.667), (1, 0.75)]. Weighted Pearson's r for P (and regular Pearson's r for P_x) is 0.9821, while regular Spearman's rho for P_x is 0.8819, i.e. weighted Spearman's rho for P should also be 0.8819.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach for computing Kendall's tau, suggested by Paul, works. You don't have to assign indices of sorted array as ranks though, indices of unsorted one work equally fine (as seen in the example with weighted tau). The weights also need not to be normalized.

Regular (unweighted) Kendall's tau (on the "expanded" dataset):

```
stats.kendalltau([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [.25, .25, .25, .25, .2, .2, .2, .667, .667, .75, .6, .6])
KendalltauResult(correlation=0.7977240352174656, pvalue=0.0034446936330652677)
```

Weighted Kendall's tau (on the dataset with occurrence counts as weights):

```
stats.weightedtau([1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
                  [.667, .25, .75, .2, .6],
                  rank=False,
                  weigher=lambda r: [2, 4, 1, 3, 2][r],
                  additive=False)
WeightedTauResult(correlation=0.7977240352174656, pvalue=nan)
```

Now, the p-value never gets computed due to the specificity of weightedtau implementation. We could approximate the p-value with the initially offered trick of scaling down the occurrences, but I'd much appreciate other approaches. Basing decisions about algorithm behavior on the available amount of memory looks like pain to me.